# How to use GCP monitoring CPU Usage alert to spin a new VM instance (implementing custom autoscaling)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have 2 GCP VMs connected to a load balancer (it is an unmanaged instance group).

I would like to spin up a new VM whenever I receive a CPU Usage alert (usage higher than 70%). This is a customized scenario and I cannot use GCP's built-in autoscaling.

Are the following 2 scenarios possible? Looking for some direction here.

1. My custom code will spin a new VM and deploy custom code on instance.
2. Can I attach the new VM to the LB afterwards?

Comment: Hello, yes it is possible to create a new instance from code and also it is possible to add an instance to your unmanaged instance group. If you have specific questions or looking for specific directions, it would be helpful to ask more specific questions, like "how do I <> using <language>/rest api?" or "how would I go about adding a new instance to an existing UIG with a gcloud command?"

Answer (score 0):

On the machine where you are running your custom code that monitors the CPU usage for the managed instance group VMs, you could use the [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1), or `gcloud` (from the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk)), by authenticating with the [key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) of a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) with the [compute.admin](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute-engine-roles) role or just through the instance metadata if you're running it in a GCE VM in your project with the [compute-rw](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes#--scopes) access scope alias, to script the instance creation and addition to your unmanaged instance group.

If you're not using custom images, you might be able to have your desired environment for the VM in a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) that you have stored in a [GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) in the project if you also give your VMs the [storage-ro](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes#--scopes) access scope alias.

For example, with Bash in a GCE VM with [compute-rw](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes#--scopes) that tracks the CPU usages:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# To be run when a scale-up is requested
IG=your-unmanaged-ig
ZONE=europe-west1-c  # (or whichever zone you'd want to spin up the VMs in)
STARTUP_SCRIPT=gs://your-gcs-bucket/your-custom-startup-script.sh  # (previously uploaded to a bucket the GCE instance can access)

# Gets the list of VMs in the IG, then increases/adds the suffix number for the new one:
lastVM="$(gcloud compute instance-groups unmanaged list-instances "$IG" --zone="$ZONE" --format='get(instance)' | grep -Po '(?<!\\)[[:alnum:]-]+$' | sort -n | tail -n1)"
lastVMno=$(grep -Eo '[0-9]+$' <<< "$lastVM" || true)
newVM="$(sed -r 's/[0-9]*$/'"$((lastVMno + 1))"'/' <<< "$lastVM")"
# Creates the new VM
gcloud compute instances create "$newVM" --zone="$ZONE" --metadata=startup-script-url="$STARTUP_SCRIPT"
# (wait for eg. the post-creation setup from your startup script to finish, then add it to the load-balanced IG)
sleep 5m  
gcloud compute instance-groups unmanaged add-instances $IG --instances="$newVM"
```